# How to "use strict" for a class within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a library that uses strict.

```
/*jslint */
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function MyLibrary() {

    }

    MyLibrary.prototype.add = function () {

    }
}());

var usersLibrary = new MyLibrary();
```

I'm trying to stick with the classical syntax for instantiating classes (using "new"). Unfortunately, I can't call myLibrary because it's scope is within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly add it to the global context:

```
(function(global) {
    'use strict';

    function myLibrary() {

    }

    myLibrary.prototype.add = function () {

    }

    global.myLibrary = myLibrary;
}(this));
```

Comment: isn't this the window?

Comment: jslint's blabbing: 'MyLibrary' was used before it was defined.

Comment: @user3448187 yes but doing it this way means the code will also work in Node.js (which may not be important).  I don't know why jslint would complain; what line is it complaining about?

Comment: it's complaining when I instantiate the class. var foo = new MyLibrary()

Comment: the error: 'MyLibrary' was used before it was defined. var foo = new MyLibrary();

Comment: @user3448187 oh OK well that's just jslint being dumb.

Comment: XD I've heard that so many times, thanks I'll just ignore it then.

Comment: Perhaps define [*myLibrary*](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html) as a global before the IIFE: `var myLibrary;`.

Comment: @RobG that works, would you say this is the "correct" way to do this. Right now I'm trying to learn the correct way of doing things. I'm also able to /*global HashState: true */ to tell JsLint that I defined it already

Comment: actually I get undefined is not a function XD, but the error is gone. So when I try to instantiate the class, it's just an empty variable

Comment: I guess if it removes the JSLint eror then it's "correct" from that perspective. :-) To me it's about coding style—declaring the variable at the top of the program makes it clear that it's intentionally global. Also, declared globals are safe from being deleted and from being overwritten by DOM elements (or perhaps other host objects) with the same name or ID.